# Run java process to read/write only to one folder

Tags: java, tomcat, javaoptions

How to run a java process to read/write only to one folder? Has the VM any option to do that?

Comment: No, but your operating system surely has some form of permissions system. Run your application with a user that can only access that folder.

Comment: You could [use security policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526008/limiting-file-access-in-java).

Comment: Using Windows as an Administrator: How to start a Java process using a standard user for which an folder has read access and all other do not have read access?